# How do I differentiate 'PASS' and 'FAIL' as booleans in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In my data set, my column name is variable so I don't know its name nor order of its occurrence. (not out of choice)

However, using `DataFrame.all()` function, I can get the boolean-only columns (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html).

However, my columns are 'PASS' and 'FAIL' and NOT boolean, how can I identify them?

Example of various table I'd get:

```
0 1    2
A Pass 3
B Fail 3

0 1    2
A qq   Pass
B nn   Fail
```

I want my function to return [1] in case 1 and [2] in case 2.

Thank you!

Edit: `Dataframe.all()` isn't right based on the comments.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please add sample code to the question. It will help understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood the purpose of `DataFrame.all()`. It does not tells you whether the columns have booleans or not. It evaluates the content of the columns (or rows) in a boolean way, and returns `True` or `False` if **all** the values are evaluated as such. It looks like do you have one column, in an unknown position, with categorical data (eventually converted to booleans), and you want to find it. Is it correct?

Comment: Ohh I see. Yes, I am trying to find all boolean columns.

Comment: I edited my question to explain more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [75]: df1
Out[75]:
   0     1  2
0  A  Pass  3
1  B  Fail  3

In [76]: df2
Out[76]:
   0   1     2
0  A  qq  Pass
1  B  nn  Fail

In [81]: df1.columns[df1.isin(['Pass','Fail']).all()]
Out[81]: Index(['1'], dtype='object')

In [82]: df2.columns[df2.isin(['Pass','Fail']).all()]
Out[82]: Index(['2'], dtype='object')
```

or using `.apply()`:

```
In [77]: df1.columns[df1.apply(lambda x: x.isin(['Pass','Fail']).all())]
Out[77]: Index(['1'], dtype='object')

In [78]: df2.columns[df2.apply(lambda x: x.isin(['Pass','Fail']).all())]
Out[78]: Index(['2'], dtype='object')
```

Explanation:

```
In [79]: df1.isin(['Pass','Fail'])
Out[79]:
       0     1      2
0  False  True  False
1  False  True  False

In [80]: df1.isin(['Pass','Fail']).all()
Out[80]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you sir! :D

Answer (score 1):

like this for example

```
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame( [ ("a","pass"), ("b","fail"), ("c","pass") ] )
>>> df
   0     1
0  a  pass
1  b  fail
2  c  pass
>>> df[1]
0    pass
1    fail
2    pass
Name: 1, dtype: object
>>> t = df[1]=="pass"
>>> t
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: 1, dtype: bool
>>> t.all()
False
>>>
```

Comment: Here, you assumed the order of boolean column. I don't know when it occurs nor do I know its name. I just know its there with "pass" and "fail"

Comment: oh, so you want to identify the column with the "pass" or "fail"?